# How to combine three table to find Avg,High,Low value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three different tables such as

```
  prac_test
UID | net_wpm
5        58
5        67

 multi_test
UID | net_wpm
5        88
5        97

 shadow_test
UID | net_wpm
5        8
5        77
```

How to combine these three tables and get avg,High,Low net wpm for UID  5

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, heres a fiddle with it :) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa438b/16

So I unioned all of the tables together and selected the `MAX`, `MIN`, and `AVG` from the `net_wpm`

```
     SELECT AVG(net_wpm),Max(net_wpm),MIN(net_wpm)
  FROM  (
select UID,net_wpm from prac_test 
union all
select UID,net_wpm from multi_test 
union all
select UID,net_wpm from shadow_test  ) sub
```